# Spring Integration: Calling transformer before handler denies transactional context

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am still fighting to realize the following flow using Spring Integration 5.5:

1. read a file from remote SFTP service as InputStream
2. transform that stream into a custom entity
3. persist the entity via JPA
4. delete remote file from SFTP server

So, I have the following flow using Java DSL:

```java
@Configuration
public class Flow {

    @Bean
    public StandardIntegrationFlow createFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(source())
            .publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> pubSub
                .subscribe(sub1 -> sub1
                    .transform(Message.class, this::transform)
                    .handle(persist(), e -> e.transactional(false))
                )
                .subscribe(sub2 -> sub2 
                    .handle(remove())
                )
            )
            .get();

    }

    public MessageSource<InputStream> source() {
        return null;
    }

    public Message<MyEntity> transform(Message<InputStream> message) {
        return null;
    }

    public JpaOutboundGateway persist() {
        return null;
    }

    public AbstractMessageHandler remove() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

My IDE (VSCode) is giving me no warning about this code, however when trying to compile it using Apache Maven 3.8 / JDK 17, I get the following compilation error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project amqp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/.../src/main/java/com/example/Flow.java:[25,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method transactional(boolean)
[ERROR]   location: variable e of type java.lang.Object
```

The reason seems to the the transformation (`transform()`), because as soon as I remove that transformation, the code compiles. Of course it fails during runtime, because `persist()` method expects a Message, not Message.

Any ideas on what is wrong with my transform-methods signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed. Looks like some bug in Java compiler by itself.
When I swap those `transform()` and `handle()` it compiles.
Or if I remove it or modify some other way...

You can use this as a workaround for now:

```
.transform(this, "transform")
```

That compiler error is fully not relevant to your `transform()` definition.

I might be mistaken judging Java compiler, so will be glad to see some other explanations and hints what is wrong with our code.

Comment: It fails same way even with `14.0.1`. At the same time I confirm that IntelliJ IDEA does not complain about any line of code and even show correct method references from any level of our code.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, it solves this issue.